# how would i improve this so it would add distance to list and then add the sum

Tags: python

```
x1 = 0.00
y1 = 0.00

distList = [] 

def coord(x1, y1):
    while True:
        x2 = int(input("Enter x: ")) 
        y2 = int(input("Enter y: ")) 
        x1 = x2
        y1 = y2
        distance = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**.5
        distList.append(distance)

def step():
    while True:

        if(x2 == 999 or y2==999):
            break
            print(sum(distList))
        else:
            coord(x1, y1)


coord(x1, y1)
```

I've been struggling to figure out how to break the loop once the user enters 999, this doesn't stop the loop for some reason and another issue is that the list distList is meant to store the distance traveled when the user enters the x and y value but it overwrites the first inputs.

Comment: Welcome to the awesome world of coding :) We're glad to have you! Try adding a few `print` statements in your `coord()` while-loop and see if you can figure out why you're never getting to the `break` in your `step` function!

Comment: Thanks for the tip!, it helped make my output much clearer but i cannot seem to get the if statement to work...

Comment: @wavejibril It doesn't look like you're calling `step()` at all in this script. Might that be why?

Comment: `coord()` function has no `break` in  `while True:` block.

Comment: should i use and instead of or?

Comment: There are multiple problems with this script. For example, `step` is never called and `x2 - x1 == 0` since `x1 = x2`. Please pick one issue to focus on. You might need to start from scratch. See [mre] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "stuck" in your `coord()` function's while-loop: You never call `step()`, so you never encounter the `if` check in that while-loop.

You also don't have any conditionals (e.g. `if`) in your `coord()` while loop, which means there's no way to "break out" of that loop!

Check out this slightly updated code:

```py
x1 = 0.00
y1 = 0.00

distList = [] 

def coord(x1, y1):
    while True:
        x2 = int(input("Enter x: ")) 
        y2 = int(input("Enter y: ")) 

        # Let the user exit out here by submitting "999"
        if x2 == 999 or y2 == 999:
            break
        x1 = x2
        y1 = y2
        distance = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**.5
        distList.append(distance)



coord(x1, y1)
```

There are a few other issues that I can see in this code; for example, if you set x1 = x2, then x2 - x1 will always be 0. **See if you can figure out what to do with the `x1 = x2` line to fix this problem!**